# Overloading Operator '+='

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Background:
I have a baseclass "Publications"
With derived classes:
-Movie
-Book
-Paper

Basically I have to overload the operator '+='; to be able to add a type String author to a certain Publication, whether it be a book, movie, or paper.

In every of these three classes I inherit from the Publication class.

Publication.h

```
#ifndef PUBLICATION_H
#define PUBLICATION_H
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Publication
  {
  public:
    Publication(string aTitle, int aYear);
    void addAuthor(const string & newAuthor);
    Publication &operator+=(const string &); 
 private: 
 std::vector<string> otherAuthors;

  };

#endif // PUBLICATION_H
```

Definitions in Publication.cpp

```
void Publication::addAuthor(const string &newAuthor)
{
    otherAuthors.push_back(newAuthor);
}

Publication &Publication::operator+=(const string &author)
{
    Publication publication(title, year);
    publication.addAuthor(author);
    return *this;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
auto book = std::make_shared<Book>("The use of lambdas in modern programming", 2014, "Addison-Wesley");
book->addAuthor("Stephen Hawkings");
book+=("Another Author"); //Here using the overloaded operator "+="
```

I get this error:

```
error: no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'std::shared_ptr<Book>' and 'const char [5]')
     book+=("Another Author");
         ^
```

Basically it is not loading the overloaded operator and Im not sure why

Comment: Why is `book` a shared_ptr? Have you tried `(*book) += ("Another Author")`?

Comment: That doesn't give me errors! Although it doesn't do anything, it doesn't add the author. And since my teacher stressed on using it, as it is safer

Comment: This is because your operator+= doesnt add anything to something. It just creates a new publication.

Answer (score 4):

Simply write `*book += "Another Author"`.

Since `book` is a `std::shared_ptr<Publication>`, `book.operator+=()` does not exist, but `*book` being a `Publication` the aforementioned construct is valid and do what is expected.

Comment: Note that parenthesis are not necessary, `*` has priority over `+=`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: Thank you very much... It's all in the little things god damnit

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 of your problem is well described by YSC. Part 2 is that your `operator+=` doesn't do anything:

```
Publication &Publication::operator+=(const string &author) {
    Publication publication(title, year); // Create a new Publication
    publication.addAuthor(author); // Add that publications author
    return *this; // Return this (publication is destroyed and no longer exists).
}
```

It is likely that you meant to do this:

```
Publication &Publication::operator+=(const string &author) {
    addAuthor(author); // Add that publications author
    return *this; // Return this 
}
```

Comment: Used your code and it works like a charm. Thanks! was a little confusing with overloading the operator.